# $error.pattern not working properly

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, validation

My cell phone number pattern is not getting applied by using the code testMessageForm.PhoneNumber.$error.pattern. I am not sure if I could even use **pattern with $error**. AngularJS documentation is no help either.

```
    **

<div class="col-sm-9">
            <input required
                   placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn"
                   ng-pattern="^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$"
                   minlength="10"
                   data-ng-model="reminderTest.PhoneNumber"
                   id="PhoneNumber"
                   name="PhoneNumber"
                   class="form-control" />  <!--ng-pattern="matchPattern"/>-->
            <span class="help-block has-error">
                <span ng-show="testMessageForm.PhoneNumber.$error.required">
                    Phone number is required
                </span>
                <span ng-show="testMessageForm.PhoneNumber.$error.minlength">
                    At least 10 digits.
                </span>
                <span ng-show="testMessageForm.PhoneNumber.$error.pattern">
                    Wrong Phone number pattern.
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngPattern` should be a regular expression.

```
ng-pattern="/^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/"
```

(notice the `/`s at the start and end)

Comment: I added your pattern to my text box as ng-pattern="\^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$\"     and I was able to add myname@mycompany.com in the phone field... does not make sense

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner he said `/` not `\`